# How do I exit a stuck/frozen crafting menu in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm currently stuck in a crafting menu in Fallout 4, specifically the Cooking menu. I was attempting to craft Vegetable Starch, maybe I was pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> too fast, as once I ran out of Corn I couldn't <kbd>Tab</kbd> back out of the menu.

I could quit and reload the game, but I haven't saved in a while so I'd like to avoid that. Is there a way to escape this menu, without quitting the game?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're playing on PC and don't mind accessing the developer console, then **Yes**.

There are a couple of commands you can use that will cause a menu exit as a side-effect. The simplest in this case is:

```
player.moveto player
```

[image: Opened dev console while interacting with cooking station]

This will fast travel or 'teleport' you to your current position. You will end up respawning on top of the crafting station you're currently accessing.

---

Otherwise you can use the `coc` command to fast travel you to a specific location. For example, open the console and type the following to teleport to Sanctuary:

```
coc sanctuaryext
```

Either one will close the current menu.

Comment: And if you're playing survival mode and _can't_ use the console? Are you out of luck then?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - As far as I can tell, yeah out of luck on survival and console versions (Xbox, PS etc). I don't have a console version to test with, but if the menu locks up like that I don't think there's much you can do - at least nothing I could find online. The only advice I can give is save early and often (which holds true for PC too)